# Validate Control using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have asp.net web application where controls are getting loaded dynamically on the web page. Lets say I have a comboBox in my aspx page and on value change event of the ComboBox I am doing Postback. ComboBox is having validator associated with it. Also there are other controls in the web page with validators.

I want to validate the comboBox control before I do postback. I am using the following javascript to do so

```
  function(s, e)
{ 
    if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') 
    { 
        Page_ClientValidate(); 
        if (!Page_IsValid) { return; } 
        Callback.PerformCallback();LoadingPanel.SetText(settingCtlPropText); LoadingPanel.Show(); 
    }
    else
    {
        Callback.PerformCallback();LoadingPanel.SetText(settingCtlPropText); LoadingPanel.Show(); 
    }
}
```

But this java script is validating the comboBox along with the other controls in the page. 
I want to validate ONLY comboBox and not other controls when any value chanded in the comboBox , before I do postback.

How can I achieve this ??

Comment: the question is unclear, be more specific like adding some code...

Comment: what they said. A code sample would go a long way

Comment: visit http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp it will help you.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

function CheckStatus(sender, args) {

```
        var questionID = '<%= this.ddlStatus.ClientID %>';
        var currentQuestion = $("#" + questionID).val();
        if (currentQuestion == 0) {

            args.IsValid = false;
            return;

        }
        else {

            args.IsValid = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```